# WSL issue, vi, vim and nano are unusable (empty terminal screen) (same isue with ubuntu 20 or debian on wsl)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, terminal, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I get a strange issue with ubuntu on wsl.

When I want to modify a txt file on Ubuntu or Debian (via WSL in Windows), the content of the terminal empties and I see nothing (the content of the text file is invisible) :

I create a simple text file with some content

[image]

And when I want to read/modify the file with vim (same issue with vi and nano), I get this empty terminal :

[image]

On this empty terminal, if I press `i` then `some text` then `escape + :x` and then `enter`, I get that :

[image]

And the text `some text` has been added to the file :

[image]

I tried Debian on WSL and I get the same issue ! impossible to use vim, vi or nano because of this issue :/

I uncheck and re-check the window feature "Windows Subsystem for Linux" but the issue still..

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT :

The return of the command $TERM :

[image]

Comment: What terminal program are you using?  What does `echo $TERM` print?

Comment: I edit my post and added the return of `echo $TERM` (xterm-256color)

Comment: thanks for help :) can you tell me how I can use the tmux terminale ? (where I must change this configuration ?)

Comment: I get an again the same issue : if I execute 'tmux' I get an empty terminale (screenshoot : https://i.ibb.co/3mnPtqR/Capture.png)

Comment: I get the same issue ! x) (https://i.ibb.co/pfW4Lvh/Capture.png)

Comment: What's `uname -a` show?  Wondering if you are seeing a kernel issue of some sort.  Also, which Windows version and release (e.g. Windows 10 20H2?)

Comment: I've run into the same issue after installing KB5007206.  More details found at: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7660

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to set $TERM to xterm-color. With this change I got vi, vim and nano working.

```
export TERM=xterm-color
```

and try your favorite editor again. And to make it permanent add it to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc

This started after installing Cumulative update for Windows Server 2019 (KB5007206). Also removing this update I was able to get vi, vim and nano working on WSL.